# Multiple update using a condition in Oracle 11gR2

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, oracle11gr2

I have been trying to create procedure in Oracle 11gR2 and what is does is dynamically perform updates to a particular table based on the input. The user may update any or all of the four attributes of the table. The following code successfully achieves the requirement.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE eis_mod_user_emp_dets_proc
(p_pres_add         eis_employees_tb.emp_present_add%TYPE     DEFAULT NULL
,p_marital_stat     eis_employees_tb.emp_marital_status%TYPE  DEFAULT NULL
,p_cont_ll          eis_employees_tb.emp_contact_ll%TYPE      DEFAULT NULL
,p_cont_mob         eis_employees_tb.emp_contact_mob%TYPE     DEFAULT NULL)
IS
BEGIN
IF  p_pres_add IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE      eis_employees_tb
    SET         emp_present_add=p_pres_add
    WHERE       emp_id = sess.g_var_uid;
    dbms_output.put_line('Present Address updated Successfully');
END IF;

IF  p_marital_stat IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE      eis_employees_tb
    SET         emp_marital_status=p_marital_stat
    WHERE       emp_id = sess.g_var_uid;
    dbms_output.put_line('Present Marital Status updated Successfully');
END IF;

IF  p_cont_ll IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE      eis_employees_tb
    SET         emp_contact_ll=p_cont_ll
    WHERE       emp_id = sess.g_var_uid;
    dbms_output.put_line('Present Landline Number updated Successfully');
END IF;

IF  p_cont_mob IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE      eis_employees_tb
    SET         emp_contact_mob=p_cont_mob 
    WHERE       emp_id = sess.g_var_uid;
    dbms_output.put_line('Present Mobile Number updated Successfully');
END IF;

END eis_mod_user_emp_dets_proc;
/
SHOW ERROR;`
```

Output After Compilation of Procedure

`PROCEDURE eis_mod_user_emp_dets_proc Compiled.
 No Errors.`

A sample execution of the procedure is:
`EXEC    global_procs_pkg.login_proc('bh104','bh104');
    EXEC    eis_mod_user_emp_dets_proc(p_pres_add=>'Bundelkhand');`

Sample output:

```
anonymous block completed
Welcome to the system bh104

anonymous block completed
Present Address updated Successfully
Present Marital Status updated Successfully
```

Is there any better way to optimize this procedure?
I want to optimize this procedure as much as possible so as to minimize the number of comparisons if possible and reduce the number of update statements as well so as to improve the performance. So I need suggestions for improving this code.

Comment: alternatively you can write dynamic sql according to input parameter and execute it in single sql statement if logic is more complex than example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Your approach is not efficient, if all of them are not null, then you are firing 4 update statements. Also it has to perform 4 context switches betwen sql engine and pl/sql engine. You can have generic dbms_output statement to say update is successful. But it is not good practice to have dbms_output as part of packages.

```
IF  p_pres_add IS NOT NULL OR p_marital_stat IS NOT NULL OR p_cont_ll IS NOT NULL OR p_cont_mob IS NOT NULL
THEN 
  UPDATE      eis_employees_tb
    SET         emp_present_add=nvl(p_pres_add, emp_present_add),
                emp_marital_status=nvl(p_marital_stat, emp_marital_status),
                emp_contact_ll=nvl(p_cont_ll, emp_contact_ll),
                emp_contact_mob=nvl(p_cont_mob, emp_contact_mob)
    WHERE       emp_id = sess.g_var_uid;
END IF;
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `IF` construct, `NVL` would handle it anyway.

Comment: If all the values are null, then there is no need of executing update statement. In most of the scenarios it is not required, but in some cases it can come handy.

Comment: Better not put default as NULL in the declaration itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is inefficient because you are doing 4 updates.

You could do it in single **UPDATE** statement using **NVL**.

```
UPDATE eis_employees_tb
SET emp_present_add     = NVL(p_pres_add, emp_present_add),
    emp_marital_status  = NVL(p_marital_stat, emp_marital_status),
    emp_contact_ll      = NVL(p_cont_ll,emp_contact_ll),
    emp_contact_mob     = NVL(p_cont_mob , emp_contact_mob)
WHERE emp_id            = sess.g_var_uid;
```

On a side note, production systems do not use **DBMS_OUTPUT**. Perhaps, you need an **OUT parameter** if you really need the output to be pushed to the caller.

Comment: I have modified my code trying to implement dynamic sql, could you please see the link and tell me if this is a better approach? http://pastebin.com/nSy53PW0

Comment: @RajorshiMukherjee No, no, no. Do not (ab)use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE for such trivial things. You should do the UPDATE as static sql, no need of dynamic sql. It will not only kill the performance, but is also hard to maintain. Why don't you try the provided answer, it is short and more efficient.

Comment: I tried using your code and needless to say it works flawlessly, however, I want to display a message that when there is no data to be updated then the user needs to be informed. How do I achieve this? should I jam it into one IF condition using AND, and then execute the rest of the statements? As for instance http://pastebin.com/gHextjW8. Here I added the code from another procedure and am checking if any of the data is missing. Should I use an IF with AND to check the validity of the Data?

Comment: @RajorshiMukherjee You want all of them must never be NULL and all the four attributes must have a value always? Because, `OR` condition would be satisfied even if one of them is null. If your requirement is that all the fields must have a value, then your approach is fine. **Why not remove the default NULL and put them as NOT NULL instead?**